# TreeView Issue for generating tree

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, treeview

I have to generate tree view dynamically, where i am finding issues to generate at nth level.

I could generate the tree in 2 levels using the following code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        TreeProvider cmsTree = new TreeProvider(MembershipContext.AuthenticatedUser);
        var node = cmsTree.SelectSingleNode(SiteContext.CurrentSiteName, "/", "en-US");

        TreeNodeCollection myChildren = node.AllChildren;
        IEnumerable<TreeNode> treeNodes = myChildren.AsEnumerable<TreeNode>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            foreach (var tree in treeNodes.Where(x => x.NodeLevel == i))
            {
                System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNode ParentNode = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNode();
                ParentNode.Text = "Document ID " + tree.DocumentID.ToString() + ". " + tree.DocumentName.ToString() + " Level " + tree.NodeLevel + " Parent " + tree.NodeParentID + " Node ID " + tree.NodeID;
                ParentNode.Value = tree.DocumentID.ToString();
                AddNodes(ParentNode);
                tvContentTree.Nodes.Add(ParentNode);
            }
        }
}
/// <summary>
/// Adding child for the parent 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="tNode"></param>
private void AddNodes(System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNode tNode)
{
        TreeProvider cmsTree = new TreeProvider(MembershipContext.AuthenticatedUser);
        var node = cmsTree.SelectSingleNode(SiteContext.CurrentSiteName, "/", "en-US");

        TreeNodeCollection myChildren = node.AllChildren;
        IEnumerable<TreeNode> treeNodes = myChildren.AsEnumerable<TreeNode>();            

        foreach (var tree in treeNodes.Where(x => x.NodeParentID == Convert.ToInt32(tNode.Value)))
        {
            System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNode ChildNode = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNode();
            ChildNode.Text = "Document ID " + tree.DocumentID.ToString() + ". " + tree.DocumentName.ToString() + " Level " + tree.NodeLevel + " Parent " + tree.NodeParentID + " Node ID " + tree.NodeID;
            ChildNode.Value = tree.DocumentID.ToString();
            tNode.ChildNodes.Add(ChildNode);  
       }
}
```

How we can rewrite the code to generate tree for nth level?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TreeProvider cmsTree = new TreeProvider(MembershipContext.AuthenticatedUser);
        var node = cmsTree.SelectSingleNode(SiteContext.CurrentSiteName, "/", "en-US");

            TreeNodeCollection myChildren = node.AllChildren;
            IEnumerable<TreeNode> treeNodes = myChildren.AsEnumerable<TreeNode>();
            foreach (var tree in treeNodes.Where(x => x.NodeLevel ==0))
            {
                System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNode ParentNode = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNode();
                ParentNode.Text = "Root";
                ParentNode.Value = tree.NodeID.ToString();
                AddNodes(ParentNode);
                tvContentTree.Nodes.Add(ParentNode);
            }           

    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Adding child for the parent 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tNode"></param>
    private void AddNodes(System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNode tNode)
    {
        TreeProvider cmsTree = new TreeProvider(MembershipContext.AuthenticatedUser);
        var node = cmsTree.SelectSingleNode(SiteContext.CurrentSiteName, "/", "en-US");

        TreeNodeCollection myChildren = node.AllChildren;
        IEnumerable<TreeNode> childTreeNodes = myChildren.AsEnumerable<TreeNode>();

        foreach (var childTree in childTreeNodes.Where(x => x.NodeParentID == Convert.ToInt32(tNode.Value)))
        {
            System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNode ChildNode = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNode();
            ChildNode.Text = childTree.DocumentName.ToString();
            ChildNode.Value = childTree.NodeID.ToString();
            tNode.ChildNodes.Add(ChildNode);                
            AddNodes(ChildNode);
        }
    }
```